# Mouse scroll event Is not working for react select inside react scrollbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, mouseevent, react-select

I am using two packages:

1. [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)
2. [reactScrollbar](https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar)

I am using [react scroller](https://github.com/souhe/reactScrollbar) for smooth scrolling in my project. Inside the react scroller I am using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) for smooth drop down.

Issue: Whenever I scroll for my [react select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) dropdown. The parent scroll event also get fired and react-select closed it's dropdown. Due to that I am unable to select the value form dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

My onWheel was scrolling the parent react-scrollbar scroll, so i added onWheel handler as follows on parent div of react select. Hope this helps

```
onWheel=(e)=>{
 e.stopPropagation();
}

<div onWheel={this.onWheel}
 <Select ../>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `menuPortalTarget={document.body}` inside select tag.Like,

```
<select
...
menuPortalTarget={document.body}/>
```

It will attach your select component with `document.body` and dropdown won't be closed during scrolling.